# Cartesian product of sample spaces?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Consider two probability spaces, e.g.,

Probability space 1:

- the sample space $\Omega_1\equiv[0,1]$
- the $\sigma$-algebra equal to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $[0,1]$, $\mathcal{B}([0,1])$
- the measure $\mathbb{P}_1:\mathcal{B}([0,1])\rightarrow [0,1]$

Probability space 2:

- the sample space $\Omega_2\equiv[0,2]$
- the $\sigma$-algebra equal to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $[0,2]$, $\mathcal{B}([0,2])$
- the measure $\mathbb{P}_2:\mathcal{B}([0,2])\rightarrow [0,2]$

What can I say about the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}_3$ and the probability measure $\mathbb{P}_3$ of the cartesian product $\Omega_3\equiv\Omega_1\times \Omega_2$? Is it obvious that
$$
\mathbb{P}_3\equiv \mathbb{P}_1\times \mathbb{P}_2
$$
and
$$
\mathcal{F}_3\equiv \mathcal{B}([0,1])\times \mathcal{B}([0,2])
$$
or it is just one of the million possible assumptions we could make
?

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathbb{P}_1\times \mathbb{P}_2$ and $\mathcal{B}([0,1])\times \mathcal{B}([0,2])$?  The usual product measure and product $\sigma$-algebra?  And what do you mean by "**the** $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}_3$ and **the** probability measure $\mathbb{P}_3$ of the cartesian product $\Omega_3\equiv\Omega_1\times \Omega_2$"?

Comment: 1) yes 2) well, that's related to my question: are the product measure and product $\sigma$-algebra just A possible measure and A possible $\sigma$-algebra for the product sample space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When someone refers to the product $\Omega_3=\Omega_1\times \Omega_2$ as a probability space, that always means they are taking the product $\sigma$-algebra and product measure unless the context makes it clear they mean something else.

That said, it's certainly not true that this is the *only* possible probability space structure on the set $\Omega_1\times\Omega_2$.  It's just the natural one that comes from the given probability space structures on $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$, and so by convention this is the "default" structure to use if you don't say otherwise.